# Advance Custom Field slider is not working

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using advance custom field plugin to create a slide. But the output is display like this.

Slider preview now:
[image]

Here is my code.

**front-page.php**

```
<?php if( have_rows('slides') ): ?>
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <?php while( have_rows('slides') ): the_row(); 
            $image = get_sub_field('image');
            $imageurl = $image['sizes']['slider'];
        ?>            
        <li><img src="<?php echo $imageurl; ?>"></li>            
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**custom.js**

```
$(window).on('load',function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });
});
```

Is also tried of using

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });
});
```

and it didn't worked.

Can someone give a solution for this.

Comment: Can you check console to see if there is any js error?

Comment: No. There are no warning or error related to slider.

Comment: Did you try clearing your cache? Also your custom.js should load after flexslider js file.

Comment: Yeah mate. I even one this in a private browser and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you confirm if your slider files are properly loading? if yes, i guess its a js conflict.

Comment: As per the screenshot attached here, images are loading one by one down. All the essential plugin/min files downloaded such as min files are latest version

Answer (score 1):

Please add `jquery.flexslider-min.js` and `flexslider.css`

After include above files then your slider will work properly.

Also make sure you have include `"jquery"`  and then add slider js

example here: [codepen](https://codepen.io/redtiki/pen/pEPWLO)

Comment: I've already downloaded files and linked them them them through functions.php =>header.php . not working

Comment: @PrivatethePenguin  indlude "jquery.flexslider-min.js" in foolter after "jquery" file.

Answer (score 0):

ADD JS and CSS to Your theme and enqueue it, yourtheme will be name of your theme

```
if (!is_admin()) {
    // jQuery (optional loading via Google CDN)
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', ('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js'), false);  
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    // Flexslider JS
    wp_enqueue_script('flexslider', '/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', null, 2, false);   
    // Flexslider CSS
    wp_enqueue_style( 'flexslider', '/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/css/flexslider.css', null, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. But I forgot to update.

```
<div class="wrap">
            <div class="cont">
            <?php if( get_field('slider_1') ): ?>
            <div class="slide" style="background-image:url('<?php the_field('slider_1'); ?>');"></div>
              <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( get_field('slider_2') ): ?>
             <div class="slide"style="background-image:url('<?php the_field('slider_2'); ?>');"></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( get_field('slider_3') ): ?>
             <div class="slide"style="background-image:url('<?php the_field('slider_3'); ?>');"></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( get_field('slider_4') ): ?>
             <div class="slide"style="background-image:url('<?php the_field('slider_4'); ?>');"></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
                <div id="nav" style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right">
                </div>
      </div>
```